# How do I make my column dynamic in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table with 2 columns as shown in example,

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When table is re-sized (ie. width is reduced), How could I make `td 2` to locate below `td 1` rather than displaying side by side?

Comment: I guess You cant do this in Table structure.
If you want to achieve the similar functionality then use Div tag

Comment: You *can* with a **lot** of CSS twisting but it's not recommended. Alternative options are available that would require **not** using tables.

Comment: In case your table cells have a bond where one of them is used for naming and the other one for describing what the first one has named you could use declaration lists instead of tables (http://www.sitepoint.com/in-defence-of-the-definition-list/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With respect to your current code, You can target the width using media queries and set the display mode of the td to `block`

***But I suggest not to use tables for dynamic reordering since more data in various rows of the table will make it difficult to manage***

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  td {
    display: block;
  }
}
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
td {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: A nice solution, but I'd be dubious about its support in older browsers. Changing the layout flow of table related elements is notoriously infuriating.

Comment: Yes it is. This is with respect to his question. He should reconsider the usage of tables for these type of situations.

Comment: hi thanks, nice solution, yes i have reconsider usage of tables thanks again

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to accomplish is generally referred to as **responsive design** and there are a number of good solutions like [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) that provide all the functionality you need.

I would suggest using something **other than tables for layout** (divs are nice). However, if you are representing data, then tables were made for this.

I highly recommend that you seek out a layout library/framework especially if you are **dealing with tabular data**, they have good established patterns that will help guide your design decisions and give you a decent blueprint for re-flowing the layout.

These sorts of frameworks will accommodate situations where the simple layout suddenly becomes more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `display:inline-block` using `style` or css

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="display:inline-block">1</td>
        <td style="display:inline-block">2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This way line breaks will be applied to the `<td>` element. Browser compatibility here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=inline-block